# iPhone appstore account name programmatically

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes, account

Is there a way in the iphone sdk to retrieve the name of the account which bought the application programmatically?

With account name I mean the name you use to login into iTunes.

**Edit**
To make it more clear, I mean the account name you can find under your iPhone settings under 'Store'.

**Edit**
Might it be accessible trough NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no documented way to do this, and if you try and hack around it, you may find yourself rejected by the AppStore reviewers. Apple tries to protect its customers info.

Comment: can i access any Unique thing depend upon the iTunes account?

Answer (score 0):

I have an addition to the question:
Is there a way at least to confirm (programmatically) that the application was purchased from AppStore?
Or, maybe, there is a way to get a list of devices IDs from AppStore that purchased my app?

The reason is the willing to determine if the application was legally purchased or not...